# UICollectionView sizeForItemAt IndexPath

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, size, cell

I'm trying to set size for my cell according to what's inside 
this is my code and it crashes and I can't find an error messege.

```
extension TimelineCollectionVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeline", for: indexPath) as? Timeline

    cell?.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    cell?.textView.sizeToFit()



    if cell?.containerView.subviews.count == 0 {
        cell?.containerHeight.constant = 1
    } else {
        cell?.containerHeight.constant = (cell?.containerView.subviews.first?.frame.size.height) ?? 80
    }

    let cellHeight = (cell?.upperView.bounds.height)! + (cell?.textView.bounds.height)! + (cell?.containerView.bounds.height)! + (cell?.lowerView.bounds.height)!


    return CGSize(width: 375, height: cellHeight)



}
```

}

reason: '-[**NSCFString setSizeHasBeenSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000076bc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109dd9d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001094d921e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109e49f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d5f005 ___forwarding_** + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d5eb88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001080d9485 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfosWithExistingSizingDictionary:] + 3691
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001080da97b -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 127
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001080d3504 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout] + 273
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001080f3d6c -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 159
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001080f4618 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 57
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010809b6d4 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 232
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107817ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106fcdbf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106fc1440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106fc12be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f4f318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f7c3ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f7cd6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d7e267 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d7e1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d628a6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 454
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010774caea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000107752c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  Moden                               0x0000000104ab4fbf main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ad4e68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Can you post the crash log, or at least the top part of the crash log?

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. BTW - there is no reason to make `cell` and optional. If it's not actually a `Timeline` instance, you want it to crash since that is a clear bug in your app. Then you can get rid of all of those needless `?` in all of the `cell` references. And then you can get rid of those nasty `!` operators (which means "crash here").

Comment: @ScottThompson I don't get a crash log, it just crashes and show my AppDelegate class (Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS~)

Comment: @rmaddy removed marks still crashing
if I return CGSize(width: 375, height: 600) with none of things up there, it works fine. but once cell is involved a crash happens and no reason is shown

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but only when I use attributed text on my cell. You should use let sizingView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyNib", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? MyCell

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `dequeueReusableCell` here.  That is only for creating new cells.  In this case you want to get an existing cell and should probably be using `func cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?` in the `UICollectionView` class.

Comment: let sizingView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyNib", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? MyCell but this does not relove the issue