# NSInvalidArgumentException setSizeHasBeenSet unrecognized selector - with attributed text

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to create dynamic cell sizes in a collection view using a sizing view.

Everything works fine If I use text, but the moment I change to attributed text everything crashes and burns.

I have a nib file with a UIlabel

```
let sizingView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyNib", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? MyCell
```

I then send my dynamic text to the cell

```
 sizingView.configureCell(promo: promo)
```

in the cell class I

```
func configureCell(promo:CMSPromotion) {
  if let mainAttributedString = promo.content?.htmlAttributedString() {
    mainText.attributedText = mainAttributedString
  }
}
```

my HTML to attributed

```
// Convert HTML to NSAttributedString
func htmlAttributedString() -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
    guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
      data: data,
      options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
      documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
    return html
}
```

The only reference to setSizeHasBeenSet I can find in all of Google is _UIFlowLayoutItem but I dont understand why this is relevant.

https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/_UIFlowLayoutItem.h

I see a similar question at 
[UICollectionView sizeForItemAt IndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955143/uicollectionview-sizeforitemat-indexpath) but on examination, it is not duplicate, since the code provided has other issues.

Comment: Could you show the whole error message? An "unrecognized selector sent to instance" gives the method called and the class object that was mismatched. Also the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround to my issue. I am guessing it has to do with the calculation being too heavy which is why it works for regular text but not for attributed text

I pre calculate all the cell heights in a background thread before I load my collection view than in the **sizeForItemAtIndexPath** I rust return the expected height from my array

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGSize {
```